# Spring boot package with difference config file

Tags: spring-boot

I have three application config file.

1. application.yml
2. application-prod.yml
3. application-dev.yml

The application.yml default `profiles.active` is `dev`, how could i package a production jar with `prod` file without modify `profiles.active` property. Something like `mvn clean package --profiles.active=prod`.

Comment: And why do u want to create separate JARs for separate environments ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do via cmd too

In the normal Spring way, you can use a spring.profiles.active Environment property to specify which profiles are active. You can specify the property in any of the usual ways, for example you could include it in your application.properties:

> spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb

or specify on the command line using the switch

> --spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html